# Stripe Subscription: This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using this code:

1. Create Customer
2. Create Payment Method
3. Attach Payment Method to Customer

And then i am calling subscription method to create subscription.

But still getting this error : Error: This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.

Kindly let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
exports.attachPaymentMethodWithCustomer = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
  try {
    ///Create Customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      description: 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)',
    });
   

    ///Create Payment Method
    const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
      type: 'card',
      card: {
        number: '4242424242424242',
        exp_month: 10,
        exp_year: 2023,
        cvc: '314',
      },
    });


    ///Attach Payment Method with Customer
    await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
      paymentMethod.id,
        {customer:customer.id}
      );

    ///Crate Product
    const product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: 'Gold Special',
    });
    

    ///Create Price
    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      unit_amount: 1000,
      currency: 'usd',
      recurring: {interval: 'month'},
      product: product.id,
    });

    ///Create Subscription
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      items: [
        {price: price.id},
      ],
      payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
      payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
      expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
    });
    console.log(subscription.id + "Subscription");
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1000,
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
    });
    const confirmPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
      paymentIntent.id,
      {payment_method: 'pm_card_visa'}
    );
    console.log(confirmPayment.id + "Subscription");
    
    // return subscription.id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    // return null;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you called the Attach PaymentMethod [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach), you still have to explicitly make it the default either for that Subscription by passing `default_payment_method: 'pm_123'` on creation, or by setting `invoice_settings[default_payment_method]: 'pm_123'` on the Customer itself after attachment.

Overall, that's why Stripe re-designed this flow earlier this year to make it drastically simpler. It flips things around where you first create the Subscription with `payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete'`. Then client-side you have to confirm the underlying PaymentIntent as you collect payment method details. That way you only make the Subscription active once the first payment succeeds. I recommend reading their end to end quickstart which covers this in details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have updated my code and now im getting Subscription Creation but The customer hasn’t attempted to pay this invoice yet.

Comment: You need to carefully read the integration docs I shared and follow them since it's clearly explained there. `default_incomplete` keeps the Subscription you create in `status: 'incomplete'` so that you confirm the underlying PaymentIntent client-side (when you normally would collect card details). In your code you create the PaymentMethod upfront with raw PANs which no one should do. Ultimately, remove `default_incomplete` entirely in your case or confirm client-side!